# How do i implement a people counter in a video

Tags: python, python-2.7, opencv

I want to count number of people going up or down using a reference line let's say in the middle of that video. Now, How do I actually implement it using python and openCV.. I saw a lot of videos showing the people counter but no one has the method or instructions on how to exactly do that.. I don't need code.. Plz just tell me the method..

Btw here is something that i tried.. But this isn't working:

```
import cv2
```

Comment: Look into [this](http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/05/25/basic-motion-detection-and-tracking-with-python-and-opencv/). It may help you.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the detailed breakdown [here](http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/11/09/pedestrian-detection-opencv/), *as pointed out in comments by leaf*, but basically you can use the OpenCV2 built-in methods to perform pedestrian detection. OpenCV ships with a pre-trained HOG + Linear SVM model that can be used to perform pedestrian detection in both images and video streams.

To separate the Up & Down counters I would split each frame on the vertical line **before** running the detection on each half separately. You can count the number of people going in the given direction in a single frame by a simple `len(contours)` while processing that frames direction half.

To track the total number of people going in a given direction you will need to detect the motion of each contour across the frame and only add a new entry to the count when a new contour is created near the entry edge of the direction frame - of course this could be confused by people sprinting through the frame, moving the opposite direction to the expected *running up the down or vice-versa* and entering the frame then backing out.

Comment: Sir more details please regarding the counter? Lets say i have identified contours in both the halves then how do i know which one is going up or down and how do i effectively keep the counter?

Comment: @sks - Expanded as requested.